# Custom Images for Sagemaker Studio

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-studio

With the recently announced changes to Sagemaker Studio, in the new Sagemaker Studio, for the jupyter lab space, is it possible to launch a custom sagemaker studio image? if yes, how do I go about creating and attaching the custom image as I am unable to find documentation related to this.

Thank you.

*update:

I found an example on
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/studio-updated-jl-admin-guide-custom-images.html

However, I find the jupyter lab statement at the end puzzling since it is not exactly standard docker file code.